# NHibernate/C# Broken Recursive Object Graph

Tags: c#, nhibernate

First off, there may be issues with this code, I didn't write it initially.

I have 3 classes: ClassA, ClassB and InheritedClassA.  ClassA and InheritedClassA are part of common code that operates on one of two databases that have only a slightly different structures for TableA, the table that InheritedClassA maps to has a few additional columns, but is otherwise identical to the table ClassA maps to.

Here are the POCO's and the mappings:

### ClassA

```
public class ClassA
{
    private IList<ClassB> _classBsBag;
    private Collection<ClassB> _classBs;

    public ClassA() { }
    public virtual Guid ClassAId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection<ClassB> ClassBs
    {
        get
        {
            return this._classBs;
        }

        set
        {
            this._classBsBag = new List<ClassB>();
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (ClassB classB in value)
                {
                    this._classBsBag.Add(classB);
                }
            }

            this._classBs = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual IList<ClassB> ClassBsBag
    {
        get
        { 
            return this._classBsBag;
        }

        set
        {
            this._classBs = (value == null) ? null : new Collection<ClassB>(value);
            this._classBsBag = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### ClassA Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="MyNamespace.ClassA, MyNamespace" lazy="false" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" table="TableA" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="ClassAId" column="ClassAId">
      <generator class="MyNamespace.GuidGenerator, MyNamespace" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" unsaved-value="0" />
    <bag name="ClassBsBag" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="ClassAId" />
      <one-to-many class="MyNamespace.ClassB, MyNamespace" not-found="ignore" />
    </bag>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### ClassB

```
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB() { }
    public virtual Guid ClassBId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

### ClassB Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="MyNamespace.ClassB, MyNamespace" lazy="false" table="TableB" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="ClassBId" type="Guid">
      <generator class="MyNamespace.GuidGenerator, MyNamespace" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" unsaved-value="0" />
    <many-to-one name="ClassA" class="MyNamespace.ClassA, MyNamespace" column="ClassAId" lazy="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### InheritedClassA

```
public class InheritedClassA : ClassA
{
    public InheritedClassA() { }        
    public virtual string AdditionalField { get; set; }
}
```

### InheritedClassA Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="MyNamespace.InheritedClassA, MyNamespace" lazy="false" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" table="TableA" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="ClassAId" column="ClassAId">
      <generator class="MyNamespace.GuidGenerator, MyNamespace" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" unsaved-value="0" />
    <property name="AdditionalField" column="AdditionalField" length="4" not-null="true" />
    <bag name="ClassBsBag" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="ClassAId" />
      <one-to-many class="MyNamespace.ClassB, MyNamespace" not-found="ignore" />
    </bag>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### The issue

ClassA works fine on TableA on both databases, insert, update and delete including deleting ClassB from the list.  InheritedClassA works the same as ClassA with the exception of deleting ClassB from the list.  Looking at the object graph, InheritedClassA has a list of ClassB and each ClassB has a ClassA that contains a list of ClassB, including any that have been removed from the InheritedClassA list.

In all honesty, this does look kind of fishy to me, but it used to work and now it doesn't and I'm trying to figure out why.  I cannot pinpoint any breaking changes in the commit history, nor do I know exactly when it quit working (very long story).

The code base has a monsterous reconciliation routine for saving collections and handling detached data and I think part of the issue may be in there.  When an InheritedClassA has one of its ClassB members removed from the list and a save is attempted, I receive the following:

> NHibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by
>   cascade (remove deleted object from associations)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to pinpoint the exact problem, but the following could perhaps be a clue.

The collections are mapped with inverse. This tells us that if instanceB1 is included in the collection owned by instanceA1, then instanceB1.ClassA should reference exactly instanceA1, and not some other instance of ClassA.

If instanceA1 and instanceA2 both include instanceB1 in their collections, instanceB1 can still only point to one A instance. Check if the offending instanceB1 is still included in some other collection. If it's resaved and its ClassA property still points to the instance of ClassA that owns the collection from which it was removed, the resave would make it appear in the collection again.